# how to calculate distance between two country to country and country to city and city to city?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

how to calculate distance between two country to country and country to city and city to city ?

Answer (score 5):

Please read http://derickrethans.nl/spatial-indexes-calculating-distance.html