# How Can I show distance between two location on map?

Tags: php, google-maps

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to calculate distance between two country to country and country to city and city to city ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5616875/how-to-calculate-distance-between-two-country-to-country-and-country-to-city-and)

I am making a courier website. I have to add a map which show the distance between two location(postcode) and calculate the distance.How can I do this.

Comment: a good starting point is looking up google maps geocoding

Comment: How is this different than [your previous question about calculating distances](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5616875/how-to-calculate-distance-between-two-country-to-country-and-country-to-city-and), in which there are *links to (somewhat mathy) instructions*?

Answer (score 0):

There are databases available online of zip codes and distance calculations. Here is one a quick search found: http://zips.sourceforge.net/#dist_calc

If you want a pre-calculated database, you can find ones like the one above, and I've even seen a few that have pre-calculated driving-distances between zip codes.

If you need more accurate "driving-distances" between two locations, you should look at the Google maps API as JohnP suggested.